# n-Meta tic tac toe strategy

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

We all know how 1-Meta tic tac toe works-standard tic tac toe. 2-Meta tic tac toe works by placing tic tac toe grids in a tic tac toe grid. Players can go in any grid at any time, and the player who wins a grid has placed his gone in the larger grid. If the game is a tie, a fair coin is flipped to determine the winner of the square.

extending this, n-Meta tic tac toe works by putting n-1-Meta tic tac toe grids in a tic tac toe grid.

The question is, what is the optimal strategy(or what are some interesting conclusions we can make about strategy) and what conclusions can we make about the game itself.

I have no idea how to approach this.

Comment: What happens if a first level game is drawn?  Does that get marked for neither player at level 2?  If so it is clearly a draw.

Comment: I think the strategy is the same. The second player can always just play on the same tic-tac-toe as the first player, and thus make each board end in a draw.

Comment: It gets marked for neither. But why does this make it clearly a draw?

Comment: @A.W.Grossbard For the reason I just said. Second player can force a draw on each individual board.

Comment: @Isaac Browne. We posted at the same time, I was responding to Ross Millikan.  I see. I should have seen that. I'm going to modify my question to make it more interesting.

Comment: OK. Sounds like a plan!

Comment: Does ​ "is a tie" ​ require that the board be filled, or just that ​ 3-in-a-row s ​ be no longer possible? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @Ricky Demer board must be filled to declare a tie.